# the use of "it" as pronoun for a plural noun

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

> It is important when using pronouns to give **it** the correct form.

I saw an English grammar post saying putting "it" in there is incorrect since it serves as singular pronoun. but I thought when it comes to picking a pronoun between "if" and "they" for plural nouns, it was a personal choice. And I've actually used "it" on many occasions as pronoun for a plural noun. is it true using "it" in this case is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct and your example is not.

The second **it** refers to **pronouns** (in the plural) and needs to be replaced with **them**. Using **it** in this context is wrong.

The difficulty with choosing between **it** and **they/their/them** generally arises from the dual use of **they** as a singular non-gender pronoun in the place of **it** where the sex/gender of the person referred to is unknown.

Most English speakers, for example, would not use **it** to refer to a child.
They prefer to say: **The child was playing on the bank when THEY fell into the stream** rather than **when IT fell into the stream**.

This complication is avoided in a number of other languages because the word **child** itself has a gender that is not related to the sex of the child concerned.

English does not have this advantage and it divides speakers who prefer the singular **they/them** as pronouns for words such as **adult, child, teenager, officer, official** and those who don't.